# javascript facebook login OPERA and SAFARI is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, safari, opera

I have this code in my site but when I am trying to logi in under apps.facebook.com/xyz
it is not working - most recent Opera popups window but it stays blank (blank popup window stays ope)
in most recent Safari in opends and close popup window and refresh page
but it will not log me in to my app:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    if ($.browser.opera) //kvoli opere
    {   


    FB.init({
      appId      : '123', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      channelUrl : 'https://www.sss.tld/channel.html'
    });
    FB.XD._transport="postmessage";
    FB.XD.PostMessage.init();

    }
    else
    {   
    FB.init({
      appId      : '123', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    });
    }


  // Additional initialization code here
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));



function loginJSokno() {      
 FB.login(function(response) { 
   // handle the response
   location.reload(true); //po prihlaseni si refreshneme page

 }, {scope: 'publish_stream,email,offline_access,create_event'});

}
</script>
```

What is wrong with this?

P.S. for safari it looks like iframe third party cookie problem but how to solve it? i tried but no luck. for opera, i have no idea what's problem